# Scroll through a sequence of divs — Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to get the window to scroll through a sequence of divs. Here is my code, but it is quite targeted, and won't work for more than one div.

```
    $('.down_arrow').click(function(e){
    $('html, body')
        .animate({scrollTop:$('.two')
        .offset()
        .top }, 'slow');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/s4qqd/1/)

Is there a way I can then go through each `$('.container')` on each `$('.arrow_down')` click?

Comment: Can you also add your HTML or provide a Fiddle. you will get a better answer

Comment: this ended the scrollTo research for me: http://www.qlambda.com/2012/10/smoothly-scroll-element-inside-div-with.html

Comment: How about defining a `global var` that holds the last `.container` we scrolled to and when you click `.down_arrow` we scroll to `$(last_container).next('.container')`?

Comment: @Snow, what if that global var is used by another script?

Comment: @Kevin Then how about creating a closure.. But I think you're missing the point.

Comment: Edited with added JSFIDDLE

Comment: @Robert shattered my global var idea :) GJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.down_arrow').click(function(e) {
    var next_container = $(this).parents(".container").next(".container");
    $('html, body')
    .animate({ scrollTop:next_container.offset().top }, 'slow');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4qqd/2/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.down_arrow').click(function(e){
    $('html, body')
        .animate(
        {
            scrollTop:$(this).closest('.container').next().offset().top 
        }, 'slow');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/st8sZ/1/)

Comment: This is a Fricken great answer!

Answer (score -1):

You should save the last scrolled container, and scroll to the next one.
Something like this:

```
var currentContainerIndex = 0;

$('.down_arrow').click(function(e){
  var currentContainer = $($('.container')[currentContainerIndex]);
  if (!currentContainer.size()) {
    currentContainerIndex = 0;
    currentContainer = $($('.container')[currentContainerIndex]);
  }
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:currentContainer.offset().top }, 'slow');
  currentContainerIndex++;
});
```

Comment: This is what I thought till I saw @Robert's answer. I didn't downvote by the way..